# "maybe"-like function for Bool and List?

Tags: haskell, catamorphism

Sometimes i find myself progamming the pattern "if the Bool is not false" or "if the list is not empty use it, otherwise use something else".

I am looking for functions for Bool and List that are what the "maybe" function is to Maybe. Are there any?

Update: I meant to use the Bool-case as a generalization of the List-case. For example when working with Data.Text as T:

```
if T.null x then x else foo x
```

I am looking to reduce such boiler plate code.

Comment: Please provide an example on that function for Bool...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is probably that there isn't such a generic function.  As djv says, you can perhaps build on Data.Monoid to write one, something like:

```
maybe' :: (Eq a, Monoid a) => b -> (a -> b) -> a -> b
maybe' repl f x = if x == mempty then repl else f x
```

But I don't know of any functions in the standard library like that (or any that could easily be composed together to do so).

Answer (score 7):

`maybe` is the catamorphism of the Maybe type.

`foldr` is the catamorphism of the list type.

`Data.Bool.bool` is the catamorphism of the Bool type.

If you had used `maybe` like: `maybe x (const y)`

You could use:  `foldr (const (const y)) x`

Your example `if T.null x then x else foo x` could be written with `bool` as

```
bool foo id (T.null x) x
```

(it takes the `False` case first, the opposite of `if`)

Answer (score 3):

Check [Data.Monoid](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Monoid.html), it's a typeclass describing data types which have a designated empty value and you can pattern-match on it to write your generic function. There are instances for `Bool` with empty value `False` and for `List` with empty value `[]`.